# While setting header in camel routes through <xpath> how can i directly convert the String to upper case?

Tags: xml, apache-camel

I have a camel route written in XML. I am fetching a boolean value from a Tag. and I am able to get the Value and use it further in the route but i want to convert the value to Uppercase while fetching the value from tag

```
<route id="something_to_do">
 <setHeader headerName="BooleanValue">
   <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//*/Weather/Winter/text()</xpath>
 </setHeader>
</route>
```

e.g

```
  <Weather>
      <Winter>true</Winter>
  <Weather>
```

I want to get this String "true" as "TRUE" while saving it in header.

Comment: Look at the xpath language and see if it has an upper case function you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xpath 1.0 you can use the translate function:

```
//*/Weather/Winter/translate(text(), "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

Note that this example will only convert the characters a through z, excluding special characters.

Comment: It says invalid xpath expression :(

Comment: I used ,

translate(//*/Weather/Winter/text(), "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

It worked thanks.